# How to databind MenuItem collection directly into XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, menuitem

I have a UserControl which contains a ListBox. And ListBox uses another UserControl as DataTemplate.

```
    <ListBox x:Uid="SectionList" x:Name="SectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <expander:ExpanderDataTemplate/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In the code behind I set the data context to ObservableCollection. ExpanderItem exposes following public properties...
string Name,
ObservableCollection MenuItems,
bool Expanded,
UserControl Control
I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface for these properties.

And my ExpanderDataTemplate looks like this...

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,1">
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Expanded}" Content="{Binding Path=Control}">
        <Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <Menu x:Name="ConfigurationMenu" Background="Transparent">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="DropDownMenuItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <Image Source="..\..\images\dropdown_arrow.gif" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="None"/>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander.Header>
    </Expander>
</Border>
```

Here, you can see that I have data bounded all four properties Expanded, Control, Name and MenuItems. All properties are getting bounded properly and visible expect MenuItems. MenuItems is ObservableCollection of System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.

I want to achieve the desired behavior when I click the DropDownMenuItem, I should see the data bounded MenuItems collection as submenu.

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Aran.

Nevermind, there was a small mistake from my code behind. I was not setting up MenuItems collection properly. It is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: can you answer with your code behind so the rest of us can see the solution?

Comment: Its been ages already, and I see your comment now. I can't recall what was the problem, but I am pretty sure it was very minor. Let me know if anyone wants to use similar thing and faces any issue.